# Squid logging to syslog-ng - program name has brackets

Tags: ubuntu, squid, syslog, syslog-ng

Using Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and Squid3 I want to log to syslog-ng

Edited */etc/squid3/squid.conf* and added the following line:

```
access_log syslog squid
```

Logs are being written but the program name "squid" is being added in brackets, while for other logs the program name isn't

```
Jul 25 17:26:23 ubuntuserver kernel: 
Jul 25 17:26:24 ubuntuserver named[1231]:
Jul 25 16:17:56 ubuntuserver (squid):
```

I assume this is squid3 telling syslog-ng "my program name is (squid)" and am unable to find anywhere to configure this differently as I would like to remove the brackets.

In syslog-ng's conf I've had a play with outputting the log and the $PROGRAM macro definitely contains the brackets too, which indicates it is coming from squid as this page indicates the below: http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-admin-guide_en.html/reference_macros.html

> PROGRAM: The name of the program sending the message. Note that the
>   content of the $PROGRAM variable may not be completely trusted as it
>   is provided by the client program that constructed the message.

How can I remove the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rewrite rule to fix up the program name anyway you want it:

```
rewrite r_brackets {
    subst ("\((.+)\)", "$1", value (PROGRAM));
};

...

log { source (...); ....; rewrite (r_brackets); destination (...); ...; };
```

Comment: Ok had a play with regex in syslog-ng - it does it's own backslash escaping so you need to double \\ the escapes. So the regex that works becomes "\\\((.+)\\\)"

Comment: Right. You can also choose which regex style you want to use, pcre or posix (if syslog-ng was compiled with PCRE support, that is): subst (...., value (PROGRAM) type (xxx)); where 'xxx' is either posix or pcre. I believe posix is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the forum post [HERE](http://forum.logzilla.pro/index.php/topic,187.msg1498.html#msg1498) - it outlines how to configure Squid with LogZilla using syslog-ng. In the post, the configs used are sending the program name properly.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I've a debian etch box running squid 2.6 and it doesn't send through the brackets